# Troubleshooting PNUnit at the client end

Tags: c#, nunit, pnunit

I'm using **PNUnit framework** (based on NUnit) to run tests in Parallel. Basically the Runner deploys the **PNUnitAgent** on a client machine and sends it an NUnit Test as a dll file (as is normal for [running PNUnit tests](http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/pnunit.aspx)).

The problem is that the test is failing unexpectedly on the client machine. I need to troubleshoot how the test is running at client end but cannot use Visual Studio as its not installed.

**How can we troubleshoot PNUnit test failures? Is there any tool or any easy way to do this?**

Expecting any quick suggestions as it is very urgent.

Comment: Can you post the errors or failure messages?

Answer (score 2):

you can review the test errors at the smoke-errors.log file, it's automatically generated by the PNunit launcher and saved, by default, on the PNunit launcher binary path.

Comment: I don't have the environment right now. I'll look for this file the next time I'm running the test cases. Thanks for your reply.